# Setxkbmap turns off NumLock LED - but not NumLock

Tags: x11, keyboard, xkb, numlock

Whenever I use setxkbmap in a terminal (or my .bashrc), the next time I press any modifier keys (ctrl, shift, alt) the NumLock LED on my keyboard goes off, but NumLock itself is still active so it's in some kind of inconsistent state.

If I now press NumLock, the LED stays off but NumLock turns off, and a second press on NumLock turns both the numpad and the LED on again. Curiously, while the LED is in this inconsistent state, pressing caps lock turns both the NumLock and CapsLock LEDs on.

The command that I have in my .bashrc causing this is `setxkbmap -option compose:ralt` but it also happens if I issue a plain `setxkbmap` with no parameters, or do anything else with that command.

Why is this happening (and am I doing something wrong)?

Dump of `Xorg -version`(I'm running Xubuntu/XFCE):

```
X.Org X Server 1.7.6
Release Date: 2010-03-17
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 2.6.24-30-server x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux xxxxx 2.6.32-41-generic #94-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 6 18:00:34 UTC 2012 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-41-generic root=UUID=xxxxx ro quiet splash
Build Date: 25 February 2012  06:57:33AM
xorg-server 2:1.7.6-2ubuntu7.11 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.16.4
```

Comment: FWIW, I am seeing the exact same issue on X.Org X Server 1.13.0 (vanilla Ubuntu 12.04.2, Das Keyboard P/N DKI-USB). [Possibly related bug report](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=183308).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [this quote](http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/Configuring_keyboards) explains it:

> Warning. setxkbmap not only alters the alphanumeric keys to the values given in the map; it also resets all other keys to the startup default. If you have assigned values to the Windows keys or the multimedia keys, these settings may be lost.

Since the default visual and system (or "actual") state of the Num Lock key presumably is *off*, I'm guessing that's why this happens at all. Why the *system* state is untouched and why this only happens when pressing certain keys is still a mystery.

Answer (score 0):

This bug sucks big time. I've reported upstream at https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=78012.

As long as you're invoking setxkbmap from a script, you can work it around by executing "numlockx off; numlockx on" afterwards. But you can't do this if you're using a desktop hotkey (e.g. Alt+Shift).